# Extracting information from Classify

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have used Mathematica's automated Classify function:

```
class = Classify[trainlist, Method -> "NeuralNetwork", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

acc = ClassifierMeasurements[class, testlist];
```

'trainlist' has 720 examples and 'testlist' has 180 examples.  I get 89% accuracy. Great. But now I would like build the network from scratch so I can understand it better. That turns out to be very difficult since Classify[] is like a black box.

[image]

[image]

The most information I can get about how the network is built is from these two tables. So I tried to build my own from this information:

```
net = NetChain[{LinearLayer[50, "Input" -> 251], 
   ElementwiseLayer["SELU"], LinearLayer[50, "Input" -> 50], 
   ElementwiseLayer["SELU"], LinearLayer[9, "Input" -> 50], 
   SoftmaxLayer["Input" -> {9}]}]

netin = NetInitialize[net]

nettrain = 
 NetTrain[netin, trainlist[[1 ;; 576]], Method -> "ADAM", 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 1000, ValidationSet -> trainlist[[577 ;; 720]]]
```

In all there are about 15500 parameters (I assume they mean weights). But when I check the accuracy, it's only 0.1111. I have nine classifications so that means it only does as well as random guessing. Why is it so difficult to build a network that does as well as the automated function?

Comment: Did you have a look at the internals of your `class`? Just do `class[[1]]` and you can see it all. Currently in 12.2.0.0 (and I think also 12.1) you can extract the internal `NetChain` from the `ClassifierFunction` just by doing `class[[1]]["Model"]["Network"]` . By the way, `Classify` might also be doing `Standardize` on your training data too.

Comment: class[[1]] yields what is in the second picture. It is slightly more revealing than Information[] but still very cryptic.

Comment: Does `ClassifierInformation` not give you what you need?

Comment: That’s what the first image gives.

Comment: @pmac `Classify` is not like a black box. `class[[1]]["Model"]["Network"]` gives you the `NetChain` used under the hood. Please try your training using  `net = class[[1]]["Model"]["Network"]` and report the accuracy.

Comment: @flinty That is essentially what I have done in the code above. I didn't standardize but I tried it again with standardization and I am getting an accuracy slightly above random chance.